# Creating a type from the value of a property of an already typed object

Tags: typescript

Preface: I think this may have been asked before, but I cannot figure out the exact way to describe it.

Say one has a type, `A`, that has one property, `a`:

```js
type A = { foo: string }
```

Say one creates a value, `a`, of type `A`:

```js
const a: A = { foo: 'bar' }
```

The question is how does one create a type from the *value* of `a.foo`. That is to say, how would one do the following:

```js
type AFoo = {something...} // type AFoo = "bar"
```

I am aware that there are some workarounds, i.e. using a no-op function + generic + `as const`:

```js
const createA = <T extends A>(a: T): T => a

const a = createA({ foo: 'bar' } as const)

type AFoo = typeof a.foo // type AFoo = "bar"
```

But is there really no other way without using a no-op function?

I was thinking that there surely should be some way of telling typescript that I want `AFoo` to look at `a.foo`, not `A.foo`. It would be nice if there was something *like* `as const` that basically achieves what the no-op function is doing, i.e. an object must abide by `A` while the object still keeps it's underlying value information (isn't destroyed by upcasting to `A`).

Comment: Nope, you are upcasting `a` to `A` so you lose that information.

Comment: No need to use type assertion in `{foo: 'bar'} as const`. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOPDpN) If you are interested in function argument inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)